# error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to install ncl on my Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.After completing all the processes of installation,the terminal gives me the following error:

```
**ncl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory.**
```

and after running *sudo apt-get install libssl.so.0.9.8,*it tells me that no such package could be found.
How can I fix this?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is ncl (I suppose it's some kind of proprietary software), it seems it is linked to an old version of libssl. Of course, you are sure as hell not going to find this old version of the library in your Ubuntu.

What you can try, though, is creating a symlink with the respective name that would point to your "real" libssl. To do that, you will need to do a couple of tricks with command line, though.

Run this:
`sudo ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl*`

That will return something in line with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0`

Note the "libssl.so.1.0.0" part or however that name may differ in your installation.

Now, enter this command:
`sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8`

Change the "libssl.so.1.0.0" to whatever you found in your system.

After you're done, try running that damn "ncl". :)

EDIT: Best of all, you can try to install the libssl package from older Ubuntu version, such as 14.04.

First, download the `libssl-0.9.8` package from the Ubuntu 14.04 version:

`wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098‌/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-‌​7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_a‌​md64.deb`

Then, just install it:

`sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb`

This should do the trick.

Comment: First,I'm appreciated to your answer! However,after doing this and typing the command "ncl",it prints the following efforts:   ncl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8: version `OPENSSL_0.9.8' not found (required by ncl).What that means?And how can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: OK, then do a different thing. First, remove that symlink by typing in `sudo rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8`. Then, download the libssl-0.9.8 package from the Ubuntu 14.04 version: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb`. Then, just install it: `sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb`. This should do the trick.

Comment: I have eventually solved this  problem by your heartful help,thank your very much! :)

Comment: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openssl098%E2%80%8C/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bmd64.deb
Reusing existing connection to security.ubuntu.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-12-29 16:12:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: @AaronFranke There are some characters in your url after openssl098 part remove that and see